# Check network status in Swift, Could not find an overload for '~=' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift

I'm using **Reachability.h** library to check the network status in my swift application.

I'm having this issue in the "cases" lines:

> Could not find an overload for '~=' that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

How can I solve it ?

```
func checkNetworkStatus(){
        var reachability = Reachability()

        var internetReachable = Reachability(hostName: "www.google.es")
        var status: NetworkStatus = internetReachable.currentReachabilityStatus()

        switch(status){
            case NotReachable:
                println("No connection")

            case ReachableViaWiFi:
                println("wifi")

            case ReachableViaWWAN:
                println("Wwan")

        }
    }
```

**Solved**

I've solved with:

> status.value

returns an integer:

- 0 : no connection
- 1 : wifi
- 2 : wwan

Comment: `~=` is the pattern matching symbol, which is implicitly used to compare `status` to each of the cases. Is `NetworkStatus` comparable to `NotReachable`? Is `NetworkStatus` an `enum`? If so, it should be `case NetworkStatus.NotReachaable` or just `.NotReachable`

Comment: I've tried it, now I get this error: 'NetworkStatus.Type' does not have a member named 'NotReachable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to replace the `NetworkStatus` declaration with the following:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NetworkStatus) {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
};
```

Apple uses the `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTION` macros to convert enums to Swift. However, the enum is not declared using this macro and it is not possible to convert it directly to Swift.

Another solution is to add (pattern matching for `NetworkStatus`)

```
func ~=(a: NetworkStatus, b : NetworkStatus) -> Bool {
    return (a.value == b.value)
}
```

but note you will need a `default:` branch in the `switch`, too.

Comment: simple solution works, after it you can compare like this: if(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus() != .NotReachable) {}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration


public class ConectionReachability
{

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool
    {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress)
            {
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0
        {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
    }
}
```